# Running database migrations during docker-compose build fails, but it works from command line

Tags: mysql, symfony, docker, docker-compose, migration

I have a `docker-compose.yml` and a `Dockerfile` that create containers for an app in Symfony 2.8.

The containers are called: `webserver` (Nginx), `app` (Symfony) and `db` (MySql).

When I create the containers, I can easily access the bash of the app and run php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate. Everything works fine.

I would like to insert the command in the `Dockerfile`, like this:

```
RUN cd /var/www && php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

but, when it arrives at that point, it just returns:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                                                                   
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  

  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                             
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  

  [PDOException]                                                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  

  [PDOException]                                                                               
  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  

doctrine:migrations:migrate [--write-sql] [--dry-run] [--query-time] [--allow-no-migration] [--configuration [CONFIGURATION]] [--db-configuration [DB-CONFIGURATION]] [--db DB] [--em EM] [--shard SHARD] [--] [<version>]


ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /var/www && php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What could the problem be? It works after I access the bash in the container, but not automatically from the script.

Comment: we had the same problem to work on we created docker-compose-php.yml for PHP and docker-compose-mysql.yml for MySQL and run the MySQL docker-compose first, this way migration did not give us the problem this was the workaround though.

Comment: Do you have any feedback or questions about the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

While the image is being built, it's not yet running on a container and attached to the network to be able to see the other containers defined in our `docker-compose.yml` file.

Not only doing DB migration during the image build is a bad idea: it's not possible if the DB it depends on it is running on a different container and trying to reach it through its internal network name.

If the DB server is connected, which was already running and had a publicly reachable hostname, and the project was configured to use **that** server instead of one running in another container, it would work. But it would still be a bad idea.